# asyncio doesn't send the entire image data over tcp

Tags: python, python-3.x, tcp, python-asyncio, python-sockets

I am trying to send an image from my local computer to a computer in the cloud using asyncio with TCP protocol. Sometimes I get the entire image being sent and sometimes only part of the image gets sent.

client code

```
import os
os.environ['PYTHONASYNCIODEBUG'] = '1'
import asyncio
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR)
async def tcp_echo_client(data, loop):
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(<ip_addr>, <port>,
                                                   loop=loop)
    print('Sending data of size: %r' % str(len(data)))
    writer.write(data)
    await writer.drain()
    #print("Message: %r" %(data))
    print(type(data))
    print('Close the socket')
    writer.write_eof()
    writer.close()

with open('sendpic0.jpg','rb') as f:
    data=f.read()
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(tcp_echo_client(data, loop))
loop.close()
```

server code:

```
import os
os.environ['PYTHONASYNCIODEBUG'] = '1'
import asyncio
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR)

async def handle_echo(reader, writer):

    data = await reader.read()
    addr = writer.get_extra_info('peername')
    #print("Received %r from %r" % (message, addr))
    print("Length of data recieved: %r" % (str(len(data))))
    #with open('recvpic0.jpg','wb') as f:
    #    f.write(data)
    print("Close the client socket")
    writer.close()
    #print("Message: %r" %(data))
    print("Received data of length: %r" %(str(len(data))))


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
data=b''
coro = asyncio.start_server(handle_echo, '', <port_number>, loop=loop)
server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)
print("Received data of length: %r" %(str(len(data))))
# Serve requests until Ctrl+C is pressed
print('Serving on {}'.format(server.sockets[0].getsockname()))
try:
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

# Close the server
server.close()
loop.run_until_complete(server.wait_closed())
loop.close()
```

I didn't give the ip address and port number on purpose but it shouldn't matter.

Here is the output:

server output

```
Received data of length: '0'
Serving on ('0.0.0.0', 50001)

Length of data recieved: '249216'
Close the client socket
Received data of length: '249216'                                                                              

Length of data recieved: '250624'       
Close the client socket                                                                          
Received data of length: '250624'

Length of data recieved: '256403'                                                                              
Close the client socket                                                  
Received data of length: '256403'
```

client output

```
$ python client.py       
Sending data of size: '256403' 
Close the socket
$ python client.py
<class 'bytes'>                                                                               
Close the socket                                                                              
$ python client.py       
Sending data of size: '256403'                                                                
<class 'bytes'>                                                                               
Close the socket
```

I am using Python 3.6.

I don't know if I am supposed to have a checking mechanism or send data in chunks? I would assume all that would happen automatically under the read function.

I adjusted the code from this website: http://asyncio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tcp_echo.html

Comment: This looks like the closing-writer bug described in detail [here](https://vorpus.org/blog/some-thoughts-on-asynchronous-api-design-in-a-post-asyncawait-world/#bug-3-closing-time). If so, replacing `asyncio.open_connection` with `fixed_open_connection` function as provided there should fix the issue.

Comment: Yup! This totally fixed it! Weird that such a bug us hiding out in main asyncio library.

Comment: I've now expanded the comment into an answer.

Comment: Python 3.7 introduced a [`wait_closed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.StreamWriter.wait_closed) method that can be used to fix this properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like the closing-writer bug described in detail [in this article](https://vorpus.org/blog/some-thoughts-on-asynchronous-api-design-in-a-post-asyncawait-world/#bug-3-closing-time).

In short, `writer.close` is not a coroutine, so you cannot wait for close to actually flush the data from asyncio's buffer to the OS. Awaiting `writer.drain()` before the `close()` doesn't help because it only pauses until the background writes reduce the buffer size to a "low watermark", and not - as one might expect - until the buffer is emptied.

**UPDATE**: As of Python 3.7, released in June 2018, the straightforward fix is to await [`writer.wait_closed()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.StreamWriter.wait_closed) at the end of `tcp_echo_writer`.

---

At the time the answer was originally written, the only available fix was to copy the implementation of `asyncio.open_connection` (not quite as bad as it sounds, since it's in essence a short a convenience function) and add a call to `transport.set_write_buffer_limits(0)`. This will make `await writer.drain()` actually wait for all data to be written to the OS (which the referenced article argues would be the right thing to do anyway!):

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def fixed_open_connection(host=None, port=None, *,
                          loop=None, limit=65536, **kwds):
    if loop is None:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    reader = asyncio.StreamReader(limit=limit, loop=loop)
    protocol = asyncio.StreamReaderProtocol(reader, loop=loop)
    transport, _ = yield from loop.create_connection(
        lambda: protocol, host, port, **kwds)
    ###### Following line added to fix buffering issues:
    transport.set_write_buffer_limits(0)
    ######
    writer = asyncio.StreamWriter(transport, protocol, reader, loop)
    return reader, writer
```

> Weird that such a bug us hiding out in main asyncio library.

I suspect that most people don't see the bug because they keep the event loop running for a longer time doing other things, so after `writer.close()` the data *eventually* gets written out and the socket closed.